# Intercept gRPC C++ calls in server and client

Tags: c++, grpc

Basic task I want to do: Provide a `Authenticate` service in gRPC server that all clients call (and supply user name and password) initially to obtain a authorization token (say JWT). Next, when other service calls are made by the client, the token should be verified.

This can be accomplished in Java APIs easily using `ServerInterceptor` and `ClientInterceptor` interfaces. In `ServerInterceptor` I can check which service is called and decide whether to allow or deny the call. On the `ClientInterceptor` side I can add the authorization token as metadata to every service call.

There is this `AuthMetadataProcessor` abstract class in C++. But not sure how to accomplish the task similar to Java APIs. Is there a way to do similar things in C++ APIs ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes. You need to subclass `AuthMetadataProcessor`, override its `Process` method and register an instance of the derived type with your service. Once that is done, all method invocations will be intercepted by `Process` and it will be given the client metadata sent with the request.

Your implementation of `Process` must decide whether authentication is required for the intercepted method (i.e., cannot be required for your `Authenticate` method, but will be required for various subsequently invoked methods). This can be done by examining the `:path` metadata key, as documented in issue [#9211](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/9211), which is a trusted value designating the intercepted method.

Your implementation of `Process` must decide whether the token is supplied in the request and is valid. This is an implementation detail, but generally `Process` refers to a store of valid tokens generated by `Authenticate`. Which is probably how you have it set up in Java already.

Unfortunately, one cannot register an AuthMetadataProcessor on top of insecure credentials, meaning that you will have to use SSL, or else attempt to intercept methods differently.

The framework also provides convenience functionality allowing you to work with a peer identity property. `Process` can call `AddProperty` on the authentication context, providing the identity implied by the token, followed by `SetPeerIdentityPropertyName`. The invoked method can then access the information using `GetPeerIdentity` and avoid remapping tokens to identities.

**AuthMetadataProcessor Implementation Example**

```
struct Const
{
    static const std::string& TokenKeyName() { static std::string _("token"); return _; }
    static const std::string& PeerIdentityPropertyName() { static std::string _("username"); return _; }    
};

class MyServiceAuthProcessor : public grpc::AuthMetadataProcessor
{

public:

    grpc::Status Process(const InputMetadata& auth_metadata, grpc::AuthContext* context, OutputMetadata* consumed_auth_metadata, OutputMetadata* response_metadata) override
    {
        // determine intercepted method
        std::string dispatch_keyname = ":path";
        auto dispatch_kv = auth_metadata.find(dispatch_keyname);
        if (dispatch_kv == auth_metadata.end())
            return grpc::Status(grpc::StatusCode::INTERNAL, "Internal Error");

        // if token metadata not necessary, return early, avoid token checking
        auto dispatch_value = std::string(dispatch_kv->second.data());
        if (dispatch_value == "/MyPackage.MyService/Authenticate")
            return grpc::Status::OK;

        // determine availability of token metadata
        auto token_kv = auth_metadata.find(Const::TokenKeyName());
        if (token_kv == auth_metadata.end())
            return grpc::Status(grpc::StatusCode::UNAUTHENTICATED, "Missing Token");

        // determine validity of token metadata
        auto token_value = std::string(token_kv->second.data());
        if (tokens.count(token_value) == 0)
            return grpc::Status(grpc::StatusCode::UNAUTHENTICATED, "Invalid Token");

        // once verified, mark as consumed and store user for later retrieval
        consumed_auth_metadata->insert(std::make_pair(Const::TokenKeyName(), token_value));     // required
        context->AddProperty(Const::PeerIdentityPropertyName(), tokens[token_value]);           // optional
        context->SetPeerIdentityPropertyName(Const::PeerIdentityPropertyName());                // optional

        return grpc::Status::OK;
    }

    std::map<std::string, std::string> tokens;
};
```

**AuthMetadataProcessor Setup within Secure Service**

```
class MyServiceImplSecure : public MyPackage::MyService::Service
{

public:

    MyServiceImplSecure(std::string _server_priv, std::string _server_cert, std::string _ca_cert) :
        server_priv(_server_priv), server_cert(_server_cert), ca_cert(_ca_cert) {}

    std::shared_ptr<grpc::ServerCredentials> GetServerCredentials()
    {
        grpc::SslServerCredentialsOptions::PemKeyCertPair pkcp;
        pkcp.private_key = server_priv;
        pkcp.cert_chain = server_cert;

        grpc::SslServerCredentialsOptions ssl_opts;
        ssl_opts.pem_key_cert_pairs.push_back(pkcp);
        ssl_opts.pem_root_certs = ca_cert;

        std::shared_ptr<grpc::ServerCredentials> creds = grpc::SslServerCredentials(ssl_opts);
        creds->SetAuthMetadataProcessor(auth_processor);
        return creds;
    }

    void GetContextUserMapping(::grpc::ServerContext* context, std::string& username)
    {
        username = context->auth_context()->GetPeerIdentity()[0].data();
    }

private:

    std::string server_priv;
    std::string server_cert;
    std::string ca_cert;

    std::shared_ptr<MyServiceAuthProcessor> auth_processor =
        std::shared_ptr<MyServiceAuthProcessor>(new MyServiceAuthProcessor());
};
```

Comment: Thanks. I did it similarly after going through some test cases in the gRPC source.

Comment: It should be auto token_value = std::string(token_kv->second.data(), token_kv->second.length()); if anyone encounter trailing garbage bytes.