# Implement a custom AuthMetadataProcessor w/o InsecureServerCredentials

Tags: c++, grpc

Hi guys i need to do this in grpc c++:

client send a Authorization : Bearer token in metadata

in server i need to:

intercept or process that metadata before resolve the request

get the metadata find if there is the autorization key/value and make my own logic to validate the token, if token is valid, continue resolving the request, if token is invalid finish the request with             return Status(grpc::StatusCode::UNAUTHENTICATED, message);

i already have my own logic for validate the token.

i see this post: [Intercept gRPC C++ calls in server and client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41051041/intercept-grpc-c-calls-in-server-and-client)

i the correct answer he crete a custom AuthMetadataProcessor

but i dont know how implements or set the custom AuthMetadataProcessor with grpc::InsecureServerCredentials() and start the server with it.

I try with:

```
   void RunServer() {
    auto cred = grpc::InsecureServerCredentials();
    cred.get()->SetAuthMetadataProcessor(
std::shared_ptr<grpc::AuthMetadataProcessor>(new grpc::MyServiceAuthProcessor(true)));
    //server address
    std::string server_address("0.0.0.0:8080");

    //our PermissionController service
    PermissionController permissionController;

    // create the server
    ServerBuilder builder;

    // Listen on the given address without any authentication mechanism.
    builder.AddListeningPort(server_address, cred);

    // Register "service" as the instance through which we'll communicate with
    // clients. In this case it corresponds to an *synchronous* service.
    builder.RegisterService(&permissionController);

    // Finally assemble the server.
    std::unique_ptr<Server> server(builder.BuildAndStart());
    std::cout << "Server listening on " << server_address << std::endl;

    // Wait for the server to shutdown. Note that some other thread must be
    // responsible for shutting down the server for this call to ever return.
    server->Wait();

}
```

but server dont start show this error:

> E0712 17:02:20.429173000       1 insecure_server_credentials.cc:34]assertion failed: 0

i want to know how its the correct way to implement its.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As of now you can't, the `grpc::AuthMetadataProcessor` doesn't work with `InsecureServerCredentials`, which is unfortunate because it would be nice to have when running a gRPC Service behind an Envoy sidecar, where TLS can be terminated.