# What is the role of grpc::AuthContext, consumed_auth_metadata and response_metadata in Process()?

Tags: c++, metadata, grpc

I've built a class that inherit grpc::AuthMetadataProcessor for assign and checking tokens for RPCs taking a cue from [this question on stack-overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41051041/intercept-grpc-c-calls-in-server-and-client) and [this implementation in the official GitHub repo](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/01596014afcadb0f535049723acbbc8d7fccd32c/test/cpp/end2end/end2end_test.cc#L228).

A part from this block comment in [auth_metadata_processor.h](https://grpc.github.io/grpc/cpp/classgrpc_1_1_auth_metadata_processor.html#aa98ff82634d4b3de2b7a7e2622c12a3c)

```
  /// context is read/write: it contains the properties of the channel peer and
  /// it is the job of the Process method to augment it with properties derived
  /// from the passed-in auth_metadata.
  /// consumed_auth_metadata needs to be filled with metadata that has been
  /// consumed by the processor and will be removed from the call.
  /// response_metadata is the metadata that will be sent as part of the
  /// response.
  /// If the return value is not Status::OK, the rpc call will be aborted with
  /// the error code and error message sent back to the client.
```

I'm having an hard time finding more resources on the use of those 3 object.

- Why I need to put consumed metadata inside consumed_auth_metadata? Security purposes maybe? Convenience purposes for me, maybe?
- Why I need to put metadata inside response_metadata in order to let them readable by the RPC? Doesn't they (the metadatas) pass through anyway (except path, authority and encodings metadata)?
- What is the purpose of grpc::AuthContext::AddProperty() and grpc::AuthContext::SetPeerIdentityPropertyName() methods?

The only thing that I'm pretty sure I've understood is that `const InputMetadata& auth_metadata` contains all the metadata brought by the call like :path, :authority, encodings, user-agent and custom metadatas and some of them will not be visible inside the RPC implementation.